# Catching exception on filenotfound

Tags: c#, exception

So it is said to catch only exceptions which you cannot predict or are exceptional.

So for example, IOExceptions instead of FileNotFoundException (As this single case can be handled with a simple file check ot avoid using exceptions as flow control).

This is my understanding of the topic, correct me if I am wrong.

However, this raises the question....why are exceptions like FileNotFoundException available?

Thanks

Comment: Bad example, checking if a File exists is not concurrency-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch exceptions that you can handle.  Your first sentence is a little off and might be what is causing your confusion.

> "So it is said to catch only exceptions which you cannot predict or are exceptional."

This should read

> "So it is said to only *throw* exceptions in situations which you cannot predict or are exceptional."

Thus, if you can handle a FileNotFoundException, then you should catch it.  There are a slew of exceptions that extend IOException and, surely, you cannot (would not want to?) handle all of them.

Comment: What circumstances would prevent me from handling a FileNotFoundException? I'm thinking I can handle FileNotFoundException by using the file exists check and in a try-catch block, right?

Comment: @dotnetdev - That saying is just stating that you only catch exceptions that your program is capable of handling so that it can fail gracefully. So, if you have a volatile file (maybe its a cache) you might catch FileNotFoundExceptions because you would just load from the database and recreate the file. The problem with just checking if a file exists is that it is a shared resource. It can be deleted. In my example, if you require the file to be there or there's nothing you can do, you can catch it to avoid a nasty message getting sent to the user.

Comment: I get you on the shared-resource thing. The problem with doing the if/else check is that the file may be deleted after this and before it is used. Given your example, I am assuming that the reload/recreate actions happen in the catch block? If there's nothing that can be done to recover in some way, then don't catch it seems. What I am not thinking of is that some files may not be loadable again (e.g. something transient), and that all files and their circumstances != same.

Comment: That's exactly the idea. You have to make that decision if you can even handle the exception. In the example, you could mark a flag to indicate that the cache doesn't exist and needs to be recreated in the catch block, or you could call a method to go load up the cache.  It all depends on your scenario. You're 100% correct with your last statment. The other thing is, if you catch a base exception, you can actually hide errors you aren't handling and cause really bad side-effects--and then have a hard time tracking down those bugs because they never surface.

Comment: On the hiding exceptions thing, this entire thread was made because I came across some advice that for very specific exceptions (like FileNotFound, which is alot more specific and specialised than IOException), use if/else to check as you can because you are checking for one basic condition, and wrap in try/catch. I guess your thoughts on this are fairly clear now. Lesson is: Use if/else with try/catch IF only I can handle the exception. If I can recover e.g. load the file again, I should catch the exception. However, all exceptions should be handled to perform logging.

Comment: It'd be better to handle the file not found condition in an else block rather than in a catch block, that would be the definition of a non-exceptional bug. If I can't handle the exception, it'd be best to just let it propagate.

Comment: The problem isn't when you check to see if the file exists. What happens when you check if it exists, and right before you do your work on the file, it gets deleted? You can't really use an if/then/else because .NET is going to throw the exception. If you can handle the exception .NET is going to throw then you use a try/catch/finally. Otherwise you let it bubble up your application until either a portion of code handles it, or your application fails. As for logging, that really depends.  If I expect the cache to die every now and then, why would I log it every time? Just catch it and move on.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. My only area of confusion now is in distinguishing an exception which cannot be handled. Wuld that be an example like loading a file which only exists in one place on a network, whereas an exception you can handle is loading a file which may exist in more than one place on the network so you can look at another destination in the case of an exception on filenotfound. I'm under the impression that handling an exception is just logging it.

Comment: This "answer" is becoming very long and not really on topic if we keep this up.  I would suggest opening up another question or searching SO (or Google it) for "Exception Handling Techniques."  A there are a few great articles on the subject floating around the interwebz that will explain it a lot better than my few characters in a comment.  I would check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx or http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/miscellaneous/article.php/c12385/ to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where the file gets deleted on the filesystem between when you check for it and perform the operation that can cause the exception.  This may seem unlikely, but this sort of thing DOES happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between best practices and absolute requirements.  It's a best practice to check for the file first before trying to access it.  However, that can't really be enforced.  Since it's an absolute requirement that the file exist before it's accessed, the framework will throw an exception to enforce this condition.

In an ideal world, there would be no exception because there would be no bugs and all programs and networks (and users!) would be absolutely perfect.